# Prediction model with lagged target variable as input

Tags: regression, prediction, lags, metric

Including a lagged version of the target variable as input naturally improves the accuracy. A disadvantage I observe is that almost all the weight (e.g. in linear regression) is put on that feature, so that the model prediction becomes just the lagged output.

Even when such a model will have highest R2 / lowest RMSE, in some cases it's desired to have lower overall accuracy, but be able to predict rare, sudden changes - and put more weight on other features therefore.

- Is there a model approach to define some kind of trade off between
  high R2 and ability to predict rare changes / events.
- Is there some metric besides R2 / RMSE that takes into account the
  requirement to predict rare changes?

Summarized I think the question is a bit similar as the unbalance problem for classification, any ideas how to approach it for regression?